# PHP : For-Loop Error

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a problem with my for-loop:

It echoes `$question[0]` and echoes `$question[1]` when I answered question `$question[0]`.

The problem is when I answer `$question[1]`, it echoes `$question[0]` instead of `$question[2]` and continues in a loop between `$question[0]` and `$question[1]`

Perhaps something is wrong with array..?

```
<?php
$question = array(
  0 => "<form action=\"\" method=\"get\"> Q1<br>
    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"q0\" value=\"tr\"> A <br>
    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"q0\" value=\"ok\"> B <br>
    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"q0\" value=\"fa\"> C &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"대답하기 Answer\"> 
    </form>",
  /* 1~4 is same thing with different name (ex. q1, q2..) */

$a = array( @$_GET['q0'], @$_GET['q1'], @$_GET['q2'], @$_GET['q3'], @$_GET['q4']);

$point = array(0,0,0,0,0);  

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    ob_start();
    echo $question[$i];

    if (isset($a[$i]) == true) {
      if ($a[$i] == "tr") {
        $point[$i] = 20;
        ob_end_clean();
      }
      elseif ($a[$i] == "ok") {
        $point[$i] = 10;
        ob_end_clean();
      }
      else {
        $point[$i] = 0;
        ob_end_clean();
      }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is your `$question` and `$a` values?

Comment: Use `var_dump()` in each condition and you'll find the issue

Comment: @Lee your loop starts at position 0 thus you will all ways attempt to get $question[0] first, and if $a[1] is not true it will kill the entire loop, which also might explain why you can not get to $question[2].. but I think you need to add a bit more code to show what is going on here.

Comment: @Lee,  does your loop work every time after answering to question ?

Comment: @Nawin I added the previous code to show $question and $a values!

Comment: @ArmKh It does work but only between $question[0] and  $question[1] it is a neverending loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your array $question has only one element at the `0` index. Try putting a form name and use the form name to get the parameter from `$_Get`. After dumping the result you should get exactly what you need.

e.g. with POST

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="myform[gender]" value="true"> A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="myform[gender]" value="false"> B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="myform[gender]" value="other"> C
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and in PHP:
`$_POST["myForm"]` should be the posted form.

```
if (isset($_POST['myform'])) {
    $values = $_POST['myform'];
}
```